# My app crashes when I try to navigate, can't seem to find issue

Tags: android, android-logcat

I can't seem to find whats wrong with my application...
Here is the logcat:

```
11-05 16:37:30.030 7867-7867/com.capstone.miguel.studentassistant E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.capstone.miguel.studentassistant, PID: 7867
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.capstone.miguel.studentassistant/com.capstone.miguel.studentassistant.user_sign.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                                                                    at com.capstone.miguel.studentassistant.user_sign.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:34)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Any idea why the application crashes?

Comment: We can help you better with the related code. Please post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have wrong casting: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Check if you use the same types in xml and in your code, probably they are different.

Comment: Err, do you mind pointing out? I can't seem to find the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @migueldeo look, you are trying to cast your TextInputEditText view to TextInputLayout  by(TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_log_email); you should change it to (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.input_log_email); and change the type of your variables private TextInputLayout inputEmail, inputPass;

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

Check the declared types match those in the layout file

Comment: Hmm, it seems that is the problem because it doesnt crash when I completely removed the code, but I was unable to resolve it. When I change the  inputEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_log_email); line to (TextInputEditText), I got an error.

Answer (score 0):

private TextInputEditText inputEmail, inputPass;

inputEmail = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.input_log_email);
inputPass = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.input_log_pass);